Почему при условии x ||(x = y), при значении x = 0, y = 21 значение X выводит 21


let x = 0, y = 21;
console.log(x ||(x = y))



Почему при условии x ||(x = y), при значении x = 0, y = 21 значение X будет 21, ведь если условие которое в скобках выполняется первым, то теперь x = 21, а соответственно левое значение переводиться в true, и по логике значение x|| это true, а соответственно оно должно остаться 0, так как 0 это false почему же тогда он присваивает к x = 21 ?

How Does Short-Circuiting Work in JavaScript?

Там прямо написано, что нужно Х прировнять к Y.. x = y.. сравнение - это == и ===

Если я не ошибаюсь то логическаий операций выполняются влева на право, и переходит к 2 условий только если перное не выполнилось

@Miha Ну да, логическая булева алгебра "ленивая". В случае "или" если слева false, то будет выполнена правая часть, что тут и происходит.

«ведь если условие которое в скобках выполняется первым» — это неверное утверждение

@Grundy, не тот дубликат. Надо про = vs ==.

@Qwertiy, не, судя по вопросу он как раз = и хотел
